# Link Props to State ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, react-props, react-state-management

I'am using reactjs and Redux to transfer data from a page to another page, 
in the first page i'am dispatching an action to save the values, 
this works good

In the second page, I have a component using this saved values 
so the this.props.values give me exactely the values 
but in this component i have to use in the render part the this.state.values

Is there a way to link this.props.values to my this.state.values in my second page ?

Comment: any code examples?

Comment: Why do uou need the values in the component's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to link this.props.values to my this.state.values in my second page ?

If that's all you want, the best way to put `props` into `state` is in the `constructor`

```
class Component extends React.Componet {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { values: props.values || [] } // [] or some default value
  }
}
```

just make sure you handle the case where the `props` value changes using `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if (!equals(this.props.values, nextProps.values)) {
    this.setState({ values: nextProps.values })
  }
}
```

`equals` is whatever you want it to be (`==`, `lodash#deepEquals`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use class like this or if you are writing in function style, pass props as argument and simply call in return as {props.values}**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class testSample extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                 console.log(props.value); //check whether you are receiving values in browser console
                this.state = { values: props.values }
              }

            render(){
             return(
                   <div>{this.state.values} </div>

              )
            }

     }

export default testSample
```

**or you can directly access them like this instead assigning to state again.**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

 class testSample extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
         console.log(props.value); //check whether you are receiving values in browser console

      }

    render(){
     return(
           <div>{this.props.values} </div>

      )
    }

export default testSample
```